# C++ members available after deletion?

Tags: c++, class, delete-operator

I compiled & ran the code pasted below and surprisingly it worked without errors. (g++/linux)
How can a deleted object have some members still available ? Is it a normal behaviour ?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class chair {
    public:
    int height;
    int x;
    int y;

    chair() {
        before = last;
        if(last!=NULL)
            last->after = this;
        else
            first = this;
        last = this;
        after = NULL;
    }

    ~chair() {
        if(before != NULL)
            before->after = after;
        else
            first = after;
        if(after != NULL)
            after->before = before;
        else
            last = before;
    }

    chair* before;
    chair* after;
    static chair* first;
    static chair* last;
};
chair* chair::first;
chair* chair::last;

int main() {
    chair *room = NULL;
    int tempx = 0;
    int tempy = 1;

    while(tempx<=3) {

        tempy = 1;
        while(tempy<=3) {
            room = new chair();
            room->x = tempx;
            room->y = tempy;
            tempy++;
        }

        tempx++;
    }

    room = chair::first;
    while(room!=NULL) {
        cout << room->x << "," << room->y << endl;
        delete room;
        room = room->after;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you are doing is **[undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)** you are accessing a deleted object.  The data you are looking at is still available and the area of memory where that information is stored hasn't been overridden yet but nothing is stopping that from happening.

Comment: It's always a good practice to simply zero the pointer once you delete it or free it.

Comment: @M. Tibbits:  I complete agree I always make a habit of doing that.

Comment: Any good memory manager will memset an entire freed memory block with a distinct pattern (like 0xdd) in debug builds to make pointer look-ups very likely to crash.

Comment: @EboMike: That's neat I had never heard of that before.

Comment: Yeah, it's a neat feature, I remember when debugging with Borland C++Builder, the memory manager would fill all 32bit dwords with `0xBAADF00D`, you could immediately spot the error when "dumping the core" at a break-point.

Answer (score 2):

`delete` doesn't change the pointer variable itself, so it still points to the old memory location.

You can try ro access that memory location, but if you will find something useful there after the object that lived there got deleted, depends on how lucky you are. Generally it's undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

By calling delete you are simply telling the program that you don't need that block of memory anymore.  It then can go and use that memory however it wants, in your case it didn't need that memory just yet so it left it as is.  Later on your program might use that block of memory and you will get garbage data if you continue to access it.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delete_%28C%2B%2B%29